# Using C# console app to prompt user and run SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write my first C# program in about 10 years.  I'm trying to query a SQL Server d/b where the user inputs a memberID and the result returns the user first name, last name and userID.
Can anyone tell me if I'm on the right track here?  Like I said, it's been a long time since I've done this.

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SQL;

string memberid = Console.ReadLine();
SqlConnection con;
SqlDataReader reader;
Console.Write("Enter memberid: ");
using(SQLConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.connectionSQL));

static void getmemberids()

  {
   SQLCommand Command = new SqlCommand("select lastname, firstname, userid 
  from table where memberid = @memberid", con);
  Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memberid", memberid);
  SQLDataReader.Reader = Command.ExecuteReader():

  {

if(reader.HasRows)
  {
    while(reader.Read())
    {
      Console.WriteLine[("{0}\t\t\t{1}   {2}   {3}", reader.GetString(0), 
reader.String(1), reader.GetInt32(3));
    }
  }
  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
  }
  reader.Close();
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend altering it to return the data to a `DataTable` and then just write the specific columns to console. Although- that may be unnecessary. It's just how I have done it in the past. If anyone else has a better option, please share

Comment: Are you having problems or are you just wondering if it can be improved? There's a [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) site if the latter. If the former, what are the problems?

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer.  My new boss at work gave this assignment to me as a bonus problem on a skill assessment test but I don't actually have anything to test it on.  I wrote this from piecing together some of my scripts from my old job.  I'm not sure if the above code would actually work or if anything else was needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to tell what the *exact* issue you are having is and you don't have an error message, so I'm guessing you're wondering if this approached the correct way?

If so, I would recommend that you create a Stored Procedure on SQL Server that accepts @memberId as a parameter and returns the row you need. Otherwise somebody could write a subquery that would be ran by the server where you were just expecting a normal @memberId value.

https://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson07

Comment: He is using a parameterized query. Just looking at this without any testing, I think the query would treat that as a parameter/value for memberid. I don’t think this is susceptible to passing a sub query to do SQL injection. I would expect no results to be returned for an invalid memberid.

Comment: I just tested it, and you can indeed do SQL Injection here. Semi-colons are big jerks and SQLCmd will just run whatever sql statement you feed it without much question. This is a tame example but someone could just as easily drop the table instead of select from it. I'm using (at) below instead of the actual symbol to prevent notifications.

DECLARE (at)name VARCHAR(64) = 'Helen'; SELECT * INTO #testTable FROM table

SELECT firstname, lastname FROM table
WHERE firstname = (at)name

SELECT * FROM  #testTable

Answer (score 0):

i think you are on the right track. When I use ado.net, I typically put the connection/command in a using statement.  In regard to the datatable comment, it may or may not be beneficial to have it in that form depending on the type of application and how you use it.  If you are just looping through and reading the data and then done with the data, you likely don’t need it in a datatable. One case where you might want it in a datatable is if you were to bind it to a grid in a GUI application.